# Using special characters (slash) in FTP credentials with WebClient

Tags: powershell, ftp, powershell-2.0, webclient

EDIT: I have discovered it's definitely the password that is causing issues. I have a forward slash in my password and cannot figure out how to get this to accept it. I've already tried replacing it with `%5B`. Changing the password is not a possibility.

```
cd v:
$username = "*********"
$password = "*********"
$usrpass = $username + ":" + $password
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient

function ftp-test 
{
    if (Test-Path v:\*.204)
    {
        $files = Get-ChildItem v:\ -name -Include *.204 | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } #gets list of only the .204 files

        foreach ($file in $files)
        {
            $ftp = "ftp://$usrpass@ftp.example.com/IN/$file"
            Write-Host $ftp
            $uri = New-Object -TypeName System.Uri -ArgumentList $ftp
            $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file)
        }
    }
}


ftp-test
```

When I run the above code I get

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:13 char:34
+             $webclient.UploadFile <<<< ($uri, $file)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Searching has brought issue with proxies, but I have no proxy that I need to get through.

I can manually upload the file with `ftp.exe`, but I'd rather do all this in PowerShell if possible instead of generating a script to use `ftp.exe` with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [URL-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the special characters. *Note that encoded slash (`/`) is `%2F`, not `%5B` (that's `[`).*

Instead of hard-coding encoded characters, use [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring):

```
$usrpass = $username + ":" + [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($password)
```

---

Or use the [`WebClient.Credentials` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.credentials), and you do not need to escape anything:

```
$webclient.Credentials =
    New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)

...

$ftp = "ftp://ftp.example.com/IN/$file"
```

---

Similarly for `(Ftp)WebRequest`: [Escape the @ character in my PowerShell FTP script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56538887/850848)

Comment: I have no idea why I thought it was %5B (also it was a backslash (\\) and I'm stupid), I ended up using the NetworkCredential method and it worked. Thanks for your help.